# can we install a SharePoint 2013 KB in SharePoint 2016 environment

Tags: excel, word

We are in process of migrating our SharePoint 2010 environment to 2016 . While we are having SiteMinder agent as authentication when we try to access the word/excel/ppt documents in Chrome browser it is asking for login credentials where as in IE it opens directly. In SP2010 we don;t see this issue as they use to open in both IE and Chrome. so while doing some research I found this article which is for SP2013. I am just curious if I can use this KB on my SP2016 environment or will it break my environment?

[Opening Office files](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_integration__sharepoint/2015/04/24/unable-to-open-sharepoint-documents-in-local-client-rich-client-from-chrome-due-to-npapi-plug-in-missing/)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. That fix would be present in 2016 RTM and up.

Comment: Hi Trevor thanks for confirming about that., We have installed the latest KB on SP2016 still I am facing the same issue of unable to open the office docs from chrome browser do you  have any thoughts on this.

Comment: Remember that the browser and Office app do not share auth cookies. IE has some extra helpers and 2010/2016 work different from each other in terms of opening files. Honestly, this is a case where SAML doesn't work that well with SharePoint and for various reasons, I don't recommend it. Best bet is to take a Fiddler session to see what/who is asking you to re-auth.

Comment: interesting thing is when I keep the site open in IE and try to open the site in chrome and open the file sin chrome it does work. strange though!